# citrix licensing with .net

Tags: .net, licensing, citrix

I know there are licensing issues surrounding Citrix. But can I build a .net winform application and host it on Citrix without paying licensing fees to Microsoft?

Im aware that they charge for MS Access if its a VBA application, but is this the case also for .net?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, If I have idea then I put it here!!!!

Comment: What exactly is your question?  You have to pay for MS Access no matter what, so your question is not clearl, what exactly are you asking about .NET?  You can develop a .NET application without paying a single dime to Microsoft if you wanted.

Comment: can I host .net applications on a citrix server without paying licensing fees to Microsoft?

Comment: @user765942 - You don't have to pay licensing fees to Microsoft to host a .NET application in any location.  .NET does not come with any fees no matter what

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked to a lawyer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a no fees to use the .Net runtime. Applications that use the .Net runtime can have a diffrent licensing scheme. I this case (your own application), you probably can run it on cytrix without paying extra to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft charges you for a license for MS Access to create an MS Access VBA database application, but you do not have to have a full license of MS Access, or pay licensing fees, to run the application you created.

That's why they provide the MS Access Runtime (all the way back to good old MS Access 97).